# Use ng-resource with local json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I am developing frontend for a project. I will use `REST API` in the future when I will integerate it with the backend but for now as I am developing the frontend I need some mock-up values. Like I have a `file.json` contanining JSON data now I want to use `ng resource` in my project to call `file.json` GET method. I did not find any way. How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Grunt / Gulp?

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be mock as much as possible the server side of you project. For task like that I’m using **QEDServer** or **ExpressJS**

### QEDServer

> **QEDServer** solves those pesky problems for you so you can focus on sharpening your front-end skills. In one small package, you get a simple web server that hosts a small "product catalog" web application and a database full of existing products. You can immediately start writing code against its **RESTLike API** that responds with JSON and XML.

- https://github.com/napcs/qedserver

### ExpressJS

> With a myriad of HTTP utility methods and Connect middleware at your disposal, creating a robust **user-friendly API** is quick and easy.

- http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4